# how to get or generate egg file from source tar file or from pypi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I want to create an egg file for pandas-profiling.

The below link has a source and does not have an egg file inside.

I'm using Databricks notebook so I cant do pip install.

please help me how can I generate egg file or any direct link to get it from pypi

https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/#files

thank you in advance.

Comment: Why egg and not wheel? Databricks notebooks support eggs but not wheels? Anyway `pandas-profiling` has a list of [dependencies](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/e7ea34547087d5ecf792604efb57facee2ec609a/setup.py#L31) so without `pip install` you're out of luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Python egg file](/questions/2026395/how-to-create-python-egg-file)

Comment: I got direct link for wheel. thanks for help!